# Ploting graph with Highchart with start and end dates

Tags: jsp, highcharts

I am plotting returns for 1 year between Jan 1 2012 to 31 Dec 2012.I have 200 days with each day having 1 return value.
I am passing all the return values as series and all dates as categories to the x-axis.

The graph comes up fine but because of too many dates can't see any thing on x-axis.

Is there a way i can only have 12 ticks on the x-axis each for a month and use 200 return values to plot the graph?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [**`highstock`**](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/) chart?

They provide you with [**`rangeSelector`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector).

Look at a [**`Demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from suggestion from previous post, you can try to use master-detail chart.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail